# How to use the Spring WebClient with Jetty, instead of Netty?

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, netty, spring-webflux

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client) it is possible to use the Spring Reactive WebClient with a different server as Netty:

> WebClient provides a higher level API over HTTP client libraries. By
>   default it uses Reactor Netty but that is pluggable with a different
>   ClientHttpConnector.

However, I was not able to find a way how to do this. If I simply change the dependency from Netty to Jetty like this:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux') {
       exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty'
}
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty', version: '2.0.0.M5'
```

my application will fail to start:

```
2017-10-30 15:40:43.328 ERROR 20298 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/ipc/netty/http/client/HttpClient
```

Obviously I need to do something more. But this [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9690) gives me the impression that WebClient cannot be used without Netty.

Is it possible to replace the Netty implementation of WebClient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, in Spring Framework, `WebClient` has only one available `ClientHttpConnector` implementation, which is powered by Reactor Netty. This explains the current situation - using `WebClient` means you need Reactor Netty as a dependency.

Note that there's an existing issue about supporting Jetty Client as an alternative, see [SPR-15092](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15092).

Answer (score 12):

Add dependency:

```
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-reactive-httpclient:1.0.3
```

And then:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
ClientHttpConnector connector = new JettyClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-jetty

Comment: Any idea on what changes should I do for SSL based requests for the same migration?

Comment: @damndemon haven't done that, but probably this snippet may be useful for you:
https://sslcontext-kickstart.com/client/spring-webclient-jetty.html