# How to create Spring WebClient from Apache Http Client

Tags: java, spring-webflux, apache-httpcomponents, spring-webclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

I want to create [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) from [HttpComponent](https://hc.apache.org/)'s org.apache.http.client.HttpClient to use it in async operations.Any idea on how to do it

Comment: I don't even have an idea what exactly you're trying to achieve. What did you do so far? Where did run into problems?

Comment: Please, provide more details

Comment: Hi Thomas Hi Sergey, 
I basically have the http client object and need to create a web client object to make async calls  as that is what is only supported for reactive programming .Unable to find a way to do that

Comment: Spring currently supports Jetty and Netty clients. See [How to use Jetty client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018963/). Basically any implementation of [ClientHttpConnector](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/reactive/ClientHttpConnector.html) will work. At this time httpcomponent's implementation is not available - it might be added in future.

Comment: Work on using [HttpClient of Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) is in progress. See [JDK 11 HttpClient integration with WebClient](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21014).

Answer (score 10):

With the release of **Spring Framework 5.3** and **Spring Boot 2.4** now there is built-in integration between **Apache HttpClient 5.0** and Spring WebClient.

```java
HttpAsyncClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpAsyncClients.custom();
clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(...);
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = clientBuilder.build();
ClientHttpConnector connector = new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(client);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
```

---

**UPDATE** (based on @kolyaiks's comment)

Necessary dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.core5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore5-reactive</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'd like to mention that you have to add some Maven dependencies to turn this on: `httpclient5`, `httpcore5-parent`, `httpcore5-reactive`

Answer (score 0):

With the org.apache.http.client.HttpClient it's hard cause it was not designed for it you could do it but that would be a quiet scatchy solution with a lot of coding yourself.
Better use something designed for like the HttpAsyncClient (also from apache btw.)

Here you find some information and a code example: 
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-ga/quickstart.html

Good luck

Comment: Can you please share what could be the dirty solution if we dont have the option to use the HttpAsyncClient as we only have the HTTPClient object available whereas we need to use the Spring Webflux based WebClient to make rest calls.